# Why doesn't nginx proxy_hide_headers directive work in this case?

Tags: nginx, proxy, headers, content-security-policy

I have an nginx server block like this, and I am trying to use the `proxy_hide_header` directive to hide the `Content-Security-Policy` response header from the proxied server because I am not running an SSL server in a local environment and so the forced upgrade caused by that header is unhelpful.

```
server {
    include conf.d/environment.conf;
    listen       80;
    server_name  ~^app.*\.acme\..*;

    location / {
        proxy_hide_header "Content-Security-Policy";
        proxy_pass $app_endpoint$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }    
}
```

If I test the nginx proxy with curl:

```
curl -s -v http://app.acme.io/app/path/ >/dev/null
```

then this happens:

```
> GET /app/path/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: app.acme.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 02 Jun 2020 14:38:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Content-Length: 4231
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
< Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
<
```

In other words, the `proxy_hide_header` directive is not having the expected effect.

[ I know the server block shown is the server block being processed, because it is the only one that references the proxied server of interest and I know that the proxied server is the one being hit. ]

Why isn't the `proxy_hide_header` directive working in this case?

Comment: Works for me. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading.

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?